How to get metaspace usage histogram
Background
The application we developed causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace even in -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m environment. This application consists of many jars, so I am guessing the OutOfMemoryError is not caused by a memory leak but by the fact that there are so many classes. So I want to know which packages or jars cause metaspace shortage.
Problem
You can use jmap to show the usage of Java heap, but I couldn't find a way to show a metaspace histogram with jmap.

jmap -histo shows a histogram for instances on the java heap, not metaspace.
jmap -clstats shows only metadata usage per classloader, not per package/jar.

Question
Is there any way to get the metaspace usage histogram?
For example, I want to know "The classes in spring-*.jar take the most part of 512M metaspace".
Out-of-the-box feature of JDK or JRE is preferable.
Edit

Metaspace OOMs occur until application redeployment (deployment is aborted by Metaspace OOM).
The application is based on Spring Boot and uses @inject heavily, so many proxy objects are likely to be generated.
The application doesn't manipulate classloaders or load classes dynamically in business logic.
The OOMs never occur when -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g (it's not desirable from a resource design perspective) is specified, even after multiple application redeployment.
The OOMs occur even in the first redeployment after restarting the JavaEE server process.
The server itself requires ~300MB of metaspace, and the application (.ear) size is 100MB~.
In application redeployment, the server consumes about 2x of .class size in .ear because of soft reference. I know -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0 mitigates it, but it's not preferable because of performance degradation.


Hi, just a few additional questions:

How quickly do you reach this point of Metaspace OOMs?
Do you do any manual things with Classloading / Classloaders? This is usually a leak in the classloading mechanism.
Do you make heavy use of Spring proxy objects? If so, please make sure they are cleaned up correctly.

I think using a profiler like VisualVM should give you a clear direction of what might be happening here.

This question is similar to: java8 "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have edited the question. The OOMs never occur when -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g is specified, even after multiple application redeployment. The OOMs occur even in the first redeployment after restarting the JavaEE server process. So I think it is unlikely to be caused by metaspace leakage.
